# Redis-server не работает service, не удаляется

Tags: redis, redis-server

Ситуация:

redis-server работал отлично, но, спустя некоторое время поменялся `dir`. Я вернул его обратно и все заработало. Погуглив этот вопрос я наткнулся на вот [этот](https://serverfault.com/questions/800295/redis-spontaneously-failed-failed-opening-rdb-for-saving-permission-denied) ответ на stackoverflow, где было сказано:

> If they have changed, someone compromised your redis server. If that's the case, check to see if your redis service is open to the public. You shouldn't be able to connect to it from an external IP.

Я решил и установил *password*.

А позже, как выяснилось, `service redis-server restart/start/stop` команды не работают - они просто зависают (приходится прерывать ctrl + c).

`service redis-server status` показывает старую дату запуска демона...

Окей, подумал я и решил переустановить его заново и как выяснилось - даже этого нельзя сделать, т.к. `apt-get purge redis-server` тоже зависает.

`apt-get install --reinstall redis-server` так же не работает.

Собственно, вопрос - как это пофиксить???